# Integrate custom Quote tool with Salesforce

Tags: apex

Is it possible to integrate a custom quote tool my company's developers created with Salesforce? Currently, when a quote is submitted via our internal tool and email outlining the specifics is sent to our sales operations.

The goal would be to integrate our tool so there is no data entry and products are automatically added to the opportunity. If this is possible, what steps would you recommend to integrate our tool with Salesforce? Should we recreate our quoting tool using Apex?

Comment: It depends. Does your tool have an API? Does it support an API? You can integrate Salesforce with pretty much anything that has an Internet connection.

Comment: Yes it does. We allow vendors to access this site too for pricing and quoting.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to work with Salesforce.

1. Build inside Salesforce as a appexchange app.
2. Build external service and integrate with Salesforce using apis.

Based on what you described, you would probably looking for second option.

Salesforce provides good set of API to enable any type of integrations. You might be interested in Rest APIs [0] to update opportunity as and when your internal data changes.

Since these apis needs User Authentication Token (Session Id), your tool must provide a mechanism for customers to specify authentication token, probably integrated via oauth [1].

[0] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_list.htm

[1] https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.We are working through the details.